# How to configure a proxy in Angular CLI

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack, proxy, angular-cli

I created a new @angular/cli project and added one http GET call in the root component. Without using a proxy this works fine.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.http
      .get('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all')
      .map(response => response.json())
      .subscribe(data => console.log(data));
  }
}
```

When I try to add the configure as describe in the [Angular CLI wiki](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-proxy) things go wrong.

My proxy.conf.json file:

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "https://dog.ceo",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

I changed the URL in the component to `/api/breeds/list/all`. And I ran `ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json`

Then I'm gertting Internal Server Error message in my browsers console. And in the terminal where I started ng serve I'm getting this message `[HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api/breeds/list/all from localhost:4200 to https://dog.ceo (EPROTO)
 (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)`

I have tried several other configuration options and multiple API's. Results are similar.

The complete code is available on GitHub: **https://github.com/ErikNijland/angular-cli-proxy-test**

Versions used:

- @angular/cli: 1.3.0
- NodeJS: v8.1.4

Note: I understand that @angular/cli is using Webpack. Which in turn is using http-proxy-middleware.

Comment: `EPROTO` smells like a protocol issue. Perhaps because you're requesting via https but have `secure` set to false? Somewhere there must be a mismatch between protocols.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it is happening because of the origin your are asking https from http. This can be solved using a flag in your proxy.

```
{
    "/api": {
    "target": "https://dog.ceo",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It's working now. I always though that origin was just the host. Apparently it's scheme+host+port...

Answer (score 0):

For me, the following worked:

### In my proxy.conf.json

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": {
        "host": "dog.ceo",
        "protocol": "https:",
        "port": 443
      },
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "logLevel": "info"
  }
}
```

### Start angular with the proxy conf

`ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json`